# drawing a map with gganimate, area fills get scrambled

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, gganimate

I'm plotting polygons representing geographical areas with points on top of that.
When I plot them statically using [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) the plot is as expected (in particular the fill color of the polygons).
However, when I add a couple of lines to make the plot animated (using [gganimate](/questions/tagged/gganimate)), the polygon fill colors are not correct anymore.

Reproducible example (animation takes a 4-6 mins to render):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(readr)


data_points <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maxtoki2/reprexes/master/points.csv")
area_map <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maxtoki2/reprexes/master/shapes.csv")

# static plot, looks as expected
ggplot(data = data_points) +
  geom_polygon(data = area_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = area_name), col = "grey70") +
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, col = species, group = id), alpha = .5) +
  coord_map() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "grey90", "B" = "grey50"), guide = F)

# animation, area fills get scrambled
# WARNING: takes 4-6 minutes
ggplot(data = data_points) +
  geom_polygon(data = area_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = area_name), col = "grey70") +
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, col = species, group = id), alpha = .5) +
  coord_map() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "grey90", "B" = "grey50"), guide = F) +
  labs(subtitle = 'Date: {frame_along}') +
  transition_reveal(date_seen)
```

Here's my session info.

> ```
> (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
> LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
> States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
> LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages: [1] gganimate_1.0.3 ggplot2_3.2.1  
> readr_1.3.1     repmis_0.5     
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       
> pillar_1.4.2      compiler_3.5.0    plyr_1.8.4       
> R.methodsS3_1.8.0 prettyunits_1.0.2  [7] R.utils_2.9.2     tools_3.5.0
> progress_1.2.2    zeallot_0.1.0     digest_0.6.21     tibble_2.1.3    
> [13] gtable_0.3.0      R.cache_0.14.0    png_0.1-7        
> pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.0       rstudioapi_0.10   [19]
> mapproj_1.2.7     curl_4.2          withr_2.1.2       httr_1.4.1      
> dplyr_0.8.3       maps_3.3.0        [25] vctrs_0.2.0       hms_0.5.1  
> grid_3.5.0        tidyselect_0.2.5  glue_1.3.1       
> data.table_1.12.4 [31] R6_2.4.0          gifski_0.8.6     
> farver_1.1.0      tweenr_1.0.1      purrr_0.3.2       magrittr_1.5    
> [37] backports_1.1.5   scales_1.0.0      assertthat_0.2.1 
> colorspace_1.4-1  labeling_0.3      stringi_1.4.3     [43]
> lazyeval_0.2.2    munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4      R.oo_1.23.0
> ```

Thanks for your help.